# Excel: Create a List of Unique Cells, Ignoring Accents

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of Greek words in Excel. Some of the cells are exact duplicates, others are exactly the same word, but accented differently (in practice, some words are accented, and some are completely unaccented). I want to create a list of only the unique words, disregarding accentuation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide some sample data together with your expected results

Comment: There is no link between the code for an accented character and its unaccented equivalent. You will need two work tables, one of all unaccented characters and every possible accented form. The other will be the unaccented version of each word, from which you can then remove duplicates.

Comment: I can show you a method to covert accented characters into non-accented then to extract list of unique characters/words. Will it work for you? Please confirm .

Comment: @Socrates, soon I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to show the method which will help you to convert Accented characters/words into non-accented (**as you have demanded through comments**) then extract list of unique characters/words.*

[image]

*Insert this VBA code as Module with the required worksheet. This will convert Accented words/characters into non-accented values.*

```
Function ChangeAccent(thestring As String)
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer
Const AccChars= "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars= "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
thestring = Replace(thestring, A, B)
Next
ChangeAccent = thestring
End Function
```

**How to use the Function:**

I'm assuming that you have list of accented words in Column A.

So write this formula in Cell B2, finish with Enter and fill it down:

```
=ChangeAccent(A2)
```

In Cell C2 write this array formula, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, then fill it down.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $B$2:$B$11), 0)),"")}
```

You get unique list of non-accented words, as I've shown through screen shot.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately my words are in the Greek alphabet, but presumable if I substituted the English alphabet in your code for the Greek alphabet, in both cases, it would work.

Comment: Better you try this code and please edit your question & show us those Greek words, will help me to alter the code if required.

Comment: You edit this with Greek alphabets,, Const AccChars= "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ" then the code will work.